# How to convert a associative array into a sorted string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I convert this js object

```
 var obj1 =  {"user1":28, "user2":87, "user3":56};
```

into a string array, sorted by value, like so:

```
["user2","user3","user1"]
```

Comment: `var sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj1).sort();` in modern browsers.

Comment: @Pointy will that not sort the keys by their name and not their value?

Comment: @Luke oh oh I see; right, the `.sort()` would need a comparator for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
var obj1 =  {"user1":28, "user2":87, "user3":56};
var a = Object.keys(obj1).sort(function(x,y){return obj1[y]-obj1[x]})
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
["user2", "user3", "user1"]
```